# The mysql_error() function of the MySQL C API doesn't print an error message when the server dies

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I made a program that connects to the MySQL server and prints data.

There's only one thing that doesn't work, but Linux doesn't display error messages when the MySQL server is dead.

It would be possible if I could know what to return to the connection when the server is off, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me.

`result : $ service mysql stop`

`Mysql error:`

OTL...

`I hope result: $ service mysql stop`

`Mysql error: The server is stopped.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"

#define DB_HOST "localhost"
#define DB_USER "root"
#define DB_PASS "1q2w3e4r"
#define DB_NAME "test"
#define DB_PORT 3306
#define UNIX_SOCKET NULL
#define CLIENT_FLAG 0

void mysql_fprintf_error(MYSQL *);
void connection_check(MYSQL *);
void query_check(MYSQL *, int);
void query_result_check(MYSQL *, MYSQL_RES *);

int main()
{
    MYSQL conn;
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(&conn);
    MYSQL_RES *query_result;
    MYSQL_ROW query_row;
    char *query;
    int query_status;
    int num_fields;
    
    // trying connect to a server
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&conn, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, 
                                                                 DB_PORT, UNIX_SOCKET, CLIENT_FLAG);
    connection_check(connection);
    
    // trying execute to a query
    query = "SELECT * FROM data";
    query_status = mysql_query(connection, query);
    query_check(connection, query_status);
    
    // get the result set
    query_result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    query_result_check(connection, query_result);
    
    // fetch all availiable rows
    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(query_result);
    while ((query_row = mysql_fetch_row(query_result)) != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", query_row[i] ? query_row[i] : NULL);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    // free the result set
    mysql_free_result(query_result);
    
    // disconnect server
    mysql_close(connection);
    
    // stop program
    return 0;
}

void mysql_fprintf_error(MYSQL *connection)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Mysql error: %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
    mysql_close(connection);
    exit(1);
}

void connection_check(MYSQL *connection)
{
    if (connection == NULL)
    {
        mysql_fprintf_error(connection);
    }
}

void query_check(MYSQL *connection, int query_status)
{
    if (query_status != 0)
    {
        mysql_fprintf_error(connection);
    }
}

void query_result_check(MYSQL *connection, MYSQL_RES *query_result)
{
    if (query_result == NULL)
    {
        mysql_fprintf_error(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to exercise the connection periodically to see if it's still alive. This does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_error` as a function call with `NULL` passed cannot tell much at all about the state of the connection.

`connection_check` should probably just display a `"could not connect"` error as `mysql_fprintf_error(NULL)` is not useful.